# Hamming distance among strings in an evolving system.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose, I begin with a single string $X=\{ X_1, X_2, .... X_n\}$ where all $X_i$ are initialized to zero. Now, I evolve the system under the following rules:

1) At each time step, a string can be exactly copied into another string. A string can only be copied once each step and any string can be copied only $k$ times. If $k \rightarrow \infty$, then $N(t)=2^t$. Here, $N(t)$ denotes no of strings at time $t$. If a string has not been copied k times, its elements evolve via the following rules in time:

2) $P(X_i(t+1)=1|X_i(t)=0)=q$. Here, t means any discrete time step and q is the probability of flip from 0 to 1.

3) $P(X_i(t+1)=0|X_i(t)=0)=1-q$.

4) $P(X_i(t+1)=1|X_i(t)=1)=1$.

5) Once a string has been copied $k$ times, its elements freeze in time.

The question is: What is the average hamming distance(HD) between 2 strings after time $t$ of system evolution?

PS: I can exactly solve the problem for $k \rightarrow \infty$ and the answer is $\langle HD(t) \rangle=2x_t(1-x_t)$ where $x_t = (1-q)^t$ and $\langle...\rangle$ denote the average. I need to solve it for finite $k$.

Any help in this regard would be of much help. Thanks.

Comment: Under $1)$if $n=4$ we start with $0000$.  When we copy it, does the new copy inherit the number of times copied?  After the first time step we would have $0000, 0000$ where the first has been copied once and the second has been copied (0/1) times.  Does the new string evolve as well, or does it have to wait one time step before evolving?

Comment: The new copy does not inherit the number of times copied. So as per your question it has been copied 0 times. For the second question, it evolves in the same time step. Doesn't wait for the second time step.